# Drupal Services Token Lifetime

Tags: rest, drupal-7, drupal-services

We have built a mobile app using Phonegap.

The login flow is as follows:

- User logs in with username/password
- Services returns a token
- Token is saved locally using localstorage
- All future requests are made with this token without issues

Now this is where we are having issues:
- We close the app for several days
- Re-open the app
- Attempt to perform a request using the token saved in localstorage
- Now we are getting a response saying "Anonymous users do not have permissions...."

My question is, what is the lifetime of a token? Is there a way to check the validity of a token?

I have been struggling with this for weeks now.

Comment: hope this custom module might help https://www.drupal.org/node/801280 create extend_login_links module for fixing your problem

Comment: For those who are having this problem, refer to: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125259/why-is-session-cookie-lifetime-set-to-23-days